# Extension to send output to multiple TVs

Tags: hardware, peripherals, screen

I want to use a Raspberry Pi in an art project, where I need to connect five old CRT TV screens to the Pi. Is there an extension which I could use to connect all the TVs to one single Pi and send individual video streams to each? The TVs could be connected by either Scart or RCA, Audio is not needed, just a video stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to display same image on all TV sets, the easiest way is to use "video distribution amplifier" (google it to get prices and pictures) to split the RCA video signal.

In simple case of 2 TVs it's possible to use just Y-split cable, but for multiple TV installation I'd recommend dedicated hardware to significantly improve the picture quality.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. In my case, each TV needs an individual stream, so the TVs should be detected as separate screens inside the Pis OS.

Comment: @Thomas feels like you need to get 5 Raspberry Pis =)

Comment: Ok, maybe this really is the most easy option.